# A Nibernate project

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I am currently working on a project where i have to map classes to database for persistence.I have understood the concept of OR impedence and how Nhibernate is helping it but I have failed to understand how exactly.All the tutorials I have come accross are console based applications where as my requirements are to build a web app preferably using asp.net and C#.

Explain the following:

--> Can you explain what would be the file structure of each applicationa and what purpose each is serving?

- Nhibernate DLLs
- Class definition of persistent object
- web-confiq
- mapping files.

--> What asp.net model must be used?I had no prior knowledge of asp.net but I have managed to grasp some concepts from w3schools on webpage and MVC model?

--> How is any element on user interface corresponds to a persistent class and how does it function? This is where I am very confused.

--> Please link me some tutorials that are easily understandable (focused on web application development)

I ll also appriciate if you try to explain things in the most simple way as I am a novice user >.<.Half the time i fail to understand what expertise are saying because of challenging terms they use.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate has nothing to do with ASP.Net, you should try understanding both technologies separated from each other.

NHibernate is a tool to persist and load data models from a database. The data model should be a close representation to the real world, not necessarily corresponding to the way you want to display the information contained in that model.

NHibernate works in both ASP.Net web forms and ASP.Net MVC. I personally prefer MVC as it resembles the stateless nature of HTTP whereas web forms try to create a stateful presentation much like windows forms. As this is done through a stateless protocol, it has its quirks. But both have their use and you should look at both of them before you decide.

Whichever you chose, NHibernate will be working in the background to communicate with the database. To separate the presentation from the data layer, you usually use separate models for the presentation. These models then contain exactly what your view or web form needs to know, ideally without even knowing where the information came from. You will need to transform your data layer models into these presentation models. I use the library AutoMapper for that taks. Several design patterns like MVC and MVVM describe how to achive the separation between data, business and presentation layer.